# Converting tuples to lists and getting rid of inner tuple/list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Here's my tuple of tuples:

```
(('dlazarov',), ('ant1',))
```

I would like to turn this into this:

```
['dlazarov', 'ant1']
```

I was trying to use this:

```
userdata = (('dlazarov',), ('ant1',))

userdata = map(list, userdata)
userdata = sum(userdata, [])
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Nevermind, I had a typo in my end.

Also - question, if you guys want to answer it - where is the best way to get better with knowledge on lists, itertools, etc. I keep using inefficient workarounds that I know well, but which are definitely inefficient, and time consuming. Hell, half the time, I have to use strings and splitting to turn things into a list.

Comment: What "doesn't seem to work" about what you already have? It produces the desired result, after all. While that's not the way I would have done it, you can't argue with success.

Comment: @kindall -- it doesn't work:  `>>> map(list, (('abc',), ('def',)))` evaluates to 
`[['abc'], ['def']]`

Comment: If you haven't already, read the whole page that I linked below.  Probably several times.  It's good stuff.

Comment: Well, sure it doesn't work *if you don't do all of it!* You forgot the `sum()` step...  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> userdata = (('dlazarov',), ('ant1',))
>>> [x[0] for x in userdata]
['dlazarov', 'ant1']
```

Answer (score 2):

The operation is called "flattening".

You can use [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to handle the common case of flattening an iterable of iterables (in your case, a tuple of tuples):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> tot = (('dlazarov',), ('ant1',))
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(tot))
['dlazarov', 'ant1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way seems to work, but here's an alternate approach:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain(*userdata))
```

This is one of the recipes from here: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes

Answer (score 0):

And of course, there's the iterative way:

```
mytuple = (('dlazarov',), ('ant1',))

mylist = []
for t in mytuple:
    mylist.append(t[0])
```